# Calculate average in android from list

Tags: android

My list is of float type and parse all value to float. I have these five values in my list. All of these have values some have float format or some have value like t1,,t2 etc.

I have to check whether the value is float format, tean take this float format and calculate average depending upon no of floats formats in the list.

```
ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();    

String btn1 = t1.getText().toString();
String btn2 = t2.getText().toString();
String btn3 = t3.getText().toString();
String btn4 = t4.getText().toString();
String btn5 = t5.getText().toString();

float num1 = Float.parseFloat(btn1);
float num2 = Float.parseFloat(btn2);
float num3 = Float.parseFloat(btn3);
float num4 = Float.parseFloat(btn4);
float num5 = Float.parseFloat(btn5);    

list.add(num1);
list.add(num2);
list.add(num3);
list.add(num4);
list.add(num5);
```

Comment: didnt understatnd the problem. Anyways, you are parsing the float from String. So everything will be float.

Comment: I moved your problem statement before your code block. It's usually easier to digest code with some context. I also cleaned up the formatting of your code block. The easiest way to put code on Stack Overflow is to paste it, then select it and pres Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This will indent the code by a further four spaces, which tells SO to treat it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions:

```
    NumberUtils.isDecimal(str);
    NumberUtils.isInteger(str);
```

So in your case, you need to add all your strings to a list, then iterate over it and check which of the elements are numbers.

```
int count = 0;
Float sum = 0f;
for(String str : stringList){
    if(NumberUtils.isDecimal(str) || NumberUtils.isInteger(str)){
        count++;
        sum+= Float.parseFloat(str);
    }
}
Float average = sum/count;
```

Comment: i need to download this library of numberutils ? please provide path ?